# AssertionError: the given combination of arguments (promise and string) is invalid for this assertion

Tags: typescript, mocha.js, chai, webdriver-io

I try use wdio + moch + chai.
This is code, which wdio generate when I config it.

```
import LoginPage from  '../pageobjects/login.page';
import SecurePage from '../pageobjects/secure.page';

describe('My Login application', () => {
it('should login with valid credentials', async () => {
    await LoginPage.open();

    await LoginPage.login('tomsmith', 'SuperSecretPassword!');
    await expect(SecurePage.flashAlert).toBeExisting();
    await expect(SecurePage.flashAlert).toHaveTextContaining(
        'You logged into a secure area!');
  });
});
```

Its ok, everything is working. But when I try add chai and use assertions from chai, my tests fail with:

AssertionError: the given combination of arguments (promise and string) is invalid for this assertion. You can use an array, a map, an object, a set, a string, or a weakset instead of a string.

I use wdio in async mode. This is my code with chai

```
import * as chai from "chai";

import LoginPage from  '../pageobjects/login.page';
import SecurePage from '../pageobjects/secure.page';

const {expect} = chai

describe('My Login application', () => {
 it('should login with valid credentials', async () => {
    await LoginPage.open();

    await LoginPage.login('tomsmith', 'SuperSecretPassword!');
    await expect(SecurePage.flashAlert).exist;
    await expect(SecurePage.flashAlert).contain(
        'You logged into a secure area!');
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first example, you're using assertions from the `expect-webdriverio` library, which are async operations. So, you have to add the `await` keyword before `expect` to await the assertion.

In the second example, you're using assertions from the `chai` library, which are not async operations. So, you don't need to add the `await` keyword before `expect`, instead of that, you have to add the `await` keyword before async operations. Besides, if you're using `chai` library for assertion you'll have to add methods such as `isExisting` and `getText`. In your case it should be:

```js
import * as chai from "chai";

import LoginPage from  '../pageobjects/login.page';
import SecurePage from '../pageobjects/secure.page';

const {expect} = chai

describe('My Login application', () => {
 it('should login with valid credentials', async () => {
    await LoginPage.open();

    await LoginPage.login('tomsmith', 'SuperSecretPassword!');

    // added ↓ added ↓                       added ↓ and changed ↓
    expect(await (await SecurePage.flashAlert).isExisting()).to.be.true;
    expect(await (await SecurePage.flashAlert).getText()).contain(
        'You logged into a secure area!');
   });
});
```

Comment: I edited as you wrote, but
Property IsExisting does not exist on type 'Promise'.  Property getText does not exist on type 'Promise'

Comment: damn, I missed one more `awaits`. So, we have to await the element before interacting. I've updated my answer. Check it out.